# PHP how to loop until confirmation.

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sms-gateway

I am doing a script to send a string via URL link to an SMS gateway and get the response from them.

They will respond with a code and text for the answer, either '**200 = SUCCESS**' or an error-code: '**-100 = UNKNOWN ERROR**' , '**-101 = MISSING PARAMETER**' , etc.

In my back-end code, I would like to know how to keep looping, waiting for the return message from the SMS Gateway with an error-code and resend my string to the SMS gateway until success or confirmation?

```
$link = "http://www.smsgateway.com/send.php?phoneno=".$phonenumber."&message=".urlencode($smsMessage);
```

Next, I use cURL to send this link and get the response:

```
$returned_content = using_cURL_function_to_get_response($link);
```

Now, my **$returned_content** will show:
Success Code: **200 = SUCCESS**

Failure Code: **-100 = UNKNOWN ERROR**

Failure Code: **-101 = MISSING PARAMETER**

and many more **-1xx** failure / error-codes

Then, I want to perform a loop to check the $returned_content, if it is a failure / error-code then send again the string via cURL to the SMS gateway.

```
if ($returned_content = 'ANY FAILURE / ERROR-CODE') {
    //redo cURL
    $link = "http://www.smsgateway.com/send.php?phoneno=".$phonenumber."&message=".urlencode($smsMessage);
    $returned_content = using_cURL_function_to_get_response($link);

    // Check the $returned_content
} else {
    // inform me the '200 = SUCCESS' via email
    mail($myEmail, $successfulSubjectt, $returned_content, $msgHeaders);
}
```

I'm not sure about this looping part, anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're trying to do is this:

```
$link = "http://www.smsgateway.com/send.php?phoneno=".$phonenumber."&message=".urlencode($smsMessage);
while ($returned_content != '200 = SUCCESS')
{
    $returned_content = using_cURL_function_to_get_response($link);
}

mail($myEmail, $successfulSubjectt, $returned_content, $msgHeaders);
```

But it's not a good idea. Suppose you never do get a success? You will have an infinite loop. You should really rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have any better suggestion for solving this case?

Comment: Maybe make the request a limited number of times and then fail? Maybe a good limit is 1.

Comment: Sorry @Elijah , I don't get what you mean.
My coding is I must perform a cURL, and pass the result into $returned_content.
And then I read the $returned_content if failure code, I need to re-perform the cURL until receive success code in $returned_content

Comment: You seem to be very optimistic. Do you suppose that any failure can be overcome with enough persistence? You should accept that there may be a case where the connection has failed and will continue to fail. Then you must handle the failure.

Answer (score 0):

So when you try to send an SMS and you get an error, you want to retry sending? How would that work?

Also, not sure, but the target server might interpret this as a DoS attack.

I think you should rethink your approach. If your goal is enabling some users to send SMS, then how about presenting them with a message saying that there was an error delivering their SMS and they should try later?